# Assembly created dynamically from Webservice - how to get the .CS code at runtime?

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamically-generated

I´m dynamically creating assemblys from a webservice. After reading the initial response stream (WSDL) I use the ServiceDescriptionImporter with a ServiceDescription to get the stream and a CodeDomProvider for compilation.

Importer

```
ServiceDescriptionImporter descriptionImporter = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
ServiceDescription serviceDescription = ServiceDescription.Read(xmlreader);
descriptionImporter.AddServiceDescription(serviceDescription, null, null);
descriptionImporter.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
descriptionImporter.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
```

Compilation

```
CodeCompileUnit codeUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace();
codeUnit.Namespaces.Add(codeNamespace);
ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings importWarnings = descriptionImporter.Import(codeNamespace, codeUnit);
if (importWarnings == 0) 
{          
    results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, codeUnit);
}
```

I now get an assembly created in my temp directory but I need a .CS file with the code (like the wsdl.exe tool would create). Is there any way not to create an assembly but only the CS Code?

I can access the XML stream before it is converted but that`s only the WSDL. I tried to create the code from my CodeDomProvider but it only creates an empty file

```
    private void CreateCSCode(string FilePathName, CodeDomProvider provider)
    {

        CodeGeneratorOptions options = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
        options.BracingStyle = "C";
        using (StreamWriter sourceWriter = new StreamWriter(FilePathName))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(new System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit(), sourceWriter, options);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the code from the compileUnit (not the CodeDom) with the "GenerateCodeFromCompileUni" Method:

```
TextWriter tw = new IndentedTextWriter(new StreamWriter(PathAndName + ".cs", false), "    ");
compiler.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(codeUnit, tw, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
```

You then should be able to compile from the created file...